# Flutter Images sliding next page

Tags: api, flutter

I am new to flutter I am stuck I want images sliding images after ontap ! like our gallery app...
but the thing is images slide from privious array...suppose 1st screen I have 10 images list I opened 6 image to next screen to show full screen and when I slide on that page I want after that image I want to see 7 no or 5 no images...hope u get my point

```
       body: Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
       Container(
        child:
        Center(
          child: Swiper(
            autoplay: false,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new PhotoView(
                imageProvider: NetworkImage(widget.Backgroundimg,),
                minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
                maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 1.5,
              );

            },
            itemCount: 10,
            viewportFraction: 1,
            scale: 0.9,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

here is my body I use json for image listing......After that sending images through widget please help me for sliding array thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Carousel Slider as it will also provide many options and suitable for gallery app.
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

add the below dependency in pubsec.yaml

```
carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
```

and see the given example in link.

use

```
initialPage: 5,
```

in  carousel_slider parameter to show the initial Image

Comment: i am coming from another page....and i use widgate to see image now what to do for slide image as previous listing

Comment: you can pass the index number, in carousel_slider to show initial image at the first place  using                                                                                                     
     initialPage: 5,

Comment: Plz check link This is my previous screen what shoud i do in that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023638/how-sliding-images-on-next-page-like-mob-gallery