# How Sliding Images on next page Like Mob gallery

Tags: flutter, sliding

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrJDn.jpg)plz helpp me here i'm new to flutter....! i have seen many tutorials on this but nothig is happen to me...! what i want is i have listing array for gridview images and then ontap button the images shows to next screen ! in that i want sliding images like page is navigating and my images is sliding with same array which shows me above code on my 1st screen ! plz give me some tip on sliding images with same array of this page....! thank you for ua time..

plz give me some coding tips on next screen which i can slide images with same array

```
   return Scaffold(
  appBar: getAppBar(),
  body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _doctorsFuture,
      builder: (context, projectSnap) {
         Map data = projectSnap.data;
        print(projectSnap);
        if (projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
            projectSnap.hasData == null) {
          return Center(
              child: Text(
                "Failed to loaed",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.red),
              ));
        } else if (projectSnap.hasData) {
          return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              primary: false,
              crossAxisSpacing: 12,
              mainAxisSpacing: 12,
              itemCount: (data["hits"] as List).length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (_selectionMode) {
                    return GridTile(
                      header: GridTileBar(
                        trailing: Icon(
                          _selectedIndexList.contains(index) ? Icons
                              .check_circle_outline : Icons
                              .radio_button_unchecked,
                          color: _selectedIndexList.contains(index) ? Colors
                              .green : Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                            ),
                            child:Image.network(
                                  data['hits'][index]['largeImageURL'],
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 100,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                )

                          ),
                          onLongPress: () {
                              _changeSelection(enable: false, index: -1);
                          },
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (_selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                                _selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                              } else {
                                _selectedIndexList.add(index);
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),

                    );
                  }
                  else {
                    return GridTile(
                      child: InkResponse(
                        child: Image.network(
                          data['hits'][index]['largeImageURL'],
                          height: 50,
                          width: 100,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        onLongPress: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _changeSelection(enable: true, index: index);
                          });
                        },
                        onTap:(){
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImageView( imgPath: data['hits'][index]['largeImageURL'],)));
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }

              },

            staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              );

        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

        }
      }
      ),

);
```

}

Comment: can we see a picture ,similar to what you want to achieve?

Comment: i placed image above the screen when you on tap u can see one single image but in my case i want slide image and when image is slide next images is come with same array of this page listing is showing